# What is "assignee of record"?

Tags: united-states, small-claims-court

I see "Assignee of Record" in some forms associated with small-claims in California, i.e. https://www.courts.ca.gov/documents/sc130.pdf. What is Assignee of Record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the party that takes title to a judgment under the California Code of Civil Procedure Sec. 673 and becomes a judgment creditor under Sec. 680.240. It has all the rights to enforce and collect the judgment against the judgment debtor under the Enforcement of Judgments Laws.

[Judicial Revenue Service](http://www.judicialrevenue.com/glossary.html)

[Cal. Code Sec. 673](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/code-of-civil-procedure/ccp-sect-673.html)

For more info, look up “assignment of judgment”.

Comment: Thanks - I found "An assignment of judgment in California generally transfers all the rights that the judgment creditor had to the assignee of record" on http://www.legaldocspro.net/blog/assignment-of-a-judgment-in-california/. I wonder why the 3rd party isn't referred to as "assignee of judgement".

Comment: Hi @rishai. It has to do with the meaning of “of record.” This means “being authoritative or sanctioned.” Hence, the lead attorney in a case (or each attorney officially working on a case) is often referred to as “attorney of record.” Similarly, the New York Times, as well as other leading newspapers on a regional basis may be called “the newspaper of record.”

Comment: Thanks again A.fm. I'm wondering why or how some 3rd party can become the Assignee of Record, after all, it's a good thing to be the beneficiary receiving money awarded by the judge - would collection agencies typically be Assignees of Record?

Comment: I don’t know definitely, @rishai, but according to this website, maybe? Someone owed money, just not sure if a collection agency itself would be one... http://www.legaldocspro.net/blog/assignment-of-a-judgment-in-california/